# svm file handling in R

Tags: r, dataset, analysis

I have a multi-label classification problem. I have a dataset available at the following link:
[dataset](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multilabel.html#siam-competition2007)

This data set is originally from siam competition 2007. The dataset comprises of aviation safety reports describing the problem(s) which occurred in certain flights. It is a multi-classification, high dimensional problem. It has 21519 rows and 30438 columns.

The dataset contains .svm format file. 
I have read the file with the help of "read.delim" in R.
After that I got following output:

> head(data[,1])
>
> [1](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multilabel.html#siam-competition2007) 18 2:0.136082763488 6:0.136082763488 7:0.136082763488
>   12:0.136082763488 20:0.136082763488 23:0.136082763488
>   32:0.136082763488 37:0.136082763488 39:0.136082763488
>   43:0.136082763488 53:0.136082763488 57:0.136082763488
>   58:0.136082763488 59:0.136082763488 60:0.136082763488
>   61:0.136082763488 62:0.136082763488 63:0.136082763488
>   64:0.136082763488 65:0.136082763488 66:0.136082763488
>   67:0.136082763488 68:0.136082763488 69:0.136082763488
>   70:0.136082763488 71:0.136082763488 72:0.136082763488
>   73:0.136082763488 74:0.136082763488 75:0.136082763488
>   76:0.136082763488 77:0.136082763488 78:0.136082763488
>   79:0.136082763488 80:0.136082763488 81:0.136082763488
>   82:0.136082763488 83:0.136082763488 84:0.136082763488
>   85:0.136082763488 86:0.136082763488 87:0.136082763488
>   88:0.136082763488 89:0.136082763488 90:0.136082763488
>   91:0.136082763488 92:0.136082763488 93:0.136082763488
>   94:0.136082763488 95:0.136082763488 96:0.136082763488
>   97:0.136082763488 98:0.136082763488 99:0.136082763488
>   [2] 1,12,13,18,20 2:0.0916698497028 4:0.0916698497028
>   6:0.0916698497028 12:0.0916698497028 14:0.0916698497028
>   16:0.0916698497028 19:0.0916698497028 23:0.0916698497028
>   26:0.0916698497028 31:0.0916698497028 32:0.0916698497028
>   33:0.0916698497028 37:0.0916698497028 53:0.0916698497028
>   57:0.0916698497028 66:0.0916698497028 71:0.0916698497028
>   72:0.0916698497028 81:0.0916698497028 83:0.0916698497028
>   84:0.0916698497028 86:0.0916698497028 90:0.0916698497028
>   92:0.0916698497028 100:0.0916698497028 101:0.0916698497028
>   102:0.0916698497028 103:0.0916698497028 104:0.0916698497028
>   105:0.0916698497028 106:0.0916698497028 107:0.0916698497028
>   108:0.0916698497028 109:0.0916698497028 110:0.0916698497028
>   111:0.0916698497028 112:0.0916698497028 113:0.0916698497028
>   114:0.0916698497028 115:0.0916698497028 116:0.0916698497028
>   117:0.0916698497028 118:0.0916698497028 119:0.0916698497028
>   120:0.0916698497028 121:0.0916698497028 122:0.0916698497028
>   123:0.0916698497028 124:0.0916698497028 125:0.0916698497028
>   126:0.0916698497028 127:0.0916698497028 128:0.0916698497028
>   129:0.0916698497028 130:0.0916698497028 131:0.0916698497028
>   132:0.0916698497028 133:0.0916698497028 134:0.0916698497028
>   135:0.0916698497028 136:0.0916698497028 137:0.0916698497028
>   138:0.0916698497028 139:0.0916698497028 140:0.0916698497028
>   141:0.0916698497028 142:0.0916698497028 143:0.0916698497028
>   144:0.0916698497028 145:0.0916698497028 146:0.0916698497028
>   147:0.0916698497028 148:0.0916698497028 149:0.0916698497028
>   150:0.0916698497028 151:0.0916698497028 152:0.0916698497028
>   153:0.0916698497028 154:0.0916698497028 155:0.0916698497028
>   156:0.0916698497028 157:0.0916698497028 158:0.0916698497028
>   159:0.0916698497028 160:0.0916698497028 161:0.0916698497028
>   162:0.0916698497028 163:0.0916698497028 164:0.0916698497028
>   165:0.0916698497028 166:0.0916698497028 167:0.0916698497028
>   168:0.0916698497028 169:0.0916698497028 170:0.0916698497028
>   171:0.0916698497028 172:0.0916698497028 173:0.0916698497028
>   174:0.0916698497028 175:0.0916698497028 176:0.0916698497028
>   177:0.0916698497028 178:0.0916698497028 179:0.0916698497028
>   180:0.0916698497028 181:0.0916698497028 182:0.0916698497028
>   183:0.0916698497028 184:0.0916698497028 185:0.0916698497028
>   186:0.0916698497028 187:0.0916698497028 188:0.0916698497028
>   189:0.0916698497028 190:0.0916698497028 191:0.0916698497028
>   192:0.0916698497028 193:0.0916698497028 194:0.0916698497028

How can I convert it into the regular dataset?

Any other method than `read.delim` for reading ".svm" file in R will also be helpful.

Comment: From the URL you posted, it looks like the svm file is supposed to be read by the [LIBSVM software](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) referenced at the top of the page you used to download the data. Have you tried to read the file with the LIBSVM software?

Comment: Ya, I have tried but it won't help. It works with few datasets available on that website. But not with this one.  @LenGreski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the solution contains a number of loops. But it solved my problem.

Below is the R-code :

```
rm(list=ls())

data <- read.delim(file.choose(),header=F)

# Now using strsplit function to create a regular dataser

temp <- list()

for(i in 1:length(data$V1)){
temp[i] <- strsplit(as.character(data$V1[i]),c(" "))
}

response <- list()

for(i in 1:length(temp)){
response[[i]] <- as.numeric(strsplit(temp[[i]][1],",")[[1]])
}

# Now working for responses
l.response <- 0

for (i in 1:length(response)){
l.response[i] <- length(response[[i]])
}

col.names <- paste(rep("R",22),1:22,sep="")



l.r <- length(temp)

df.response <- data.frame(R1=rep(0,l.r),R2=rep(0,l.r),R3=rep(0,l.r),R4=rep(0,l.r),R5=rep(0,l.r)
                         ,R6=rep(0,l.r),R7=rep(0,l.r),R8=rep(0,l.r),R9=rep(0,l.r),R10=rep(0,l.r)
                         ,R11=rep(0,l.r),R12=rep(0,l.r),R13=rep(0,l.r),R14=rep(0,l.r),R15=rep(0,l.r)
                         ,R16=rep(0,l.r),R17=rep(0,l.r),R18=rep(0,l.r),R19=rep(0,l.r),R20=rep(0,l.r)
                         ,R21=rep(0,l.r),R22=rep(0,l.r))



for(i in 1:length(response)){
df.response[i,(response[[i]]+1)] <- 1
}

feature <- c(0)
value <- c(0)

v.l <- 21519

v.list <- list()
list.name <- paste(rep("V",v.l),1:v.l,sep="")

f.vec <- 0
v.vec <- 0

for(i in 1:length(temp)){
for(j in 2:length(temp[[i]])){

f.vec[j-1] <- as.numeric(strsplit(temp[[i]][j],":")[[1]])[1]
v.vec[j-1] <- as.numeric(strsplit(temp[[i]][j],":")[[1]])[2]

}

v.list[[i]] <- data.frame(f.vec,v.vec)

}

feature.name <- paste(rep("V",30438),1:30438,sep="")

v.l <- 21519

variables <- data.frame(temp = rep(0,v.l))

for(i in 1:length(feature.name)){

variables[,feature.name[i]] <- rep(0,v.l)

}


variables <- variables[,-1]

copy.variables <- variables

for(i in 1:100){

pos <- v.list[[i]][,"f.vec"]
replace <- v.list[[i]][,"v.vec"]

if(length(unique(pos))!=length(pos)){
repeat{

uni <- as.numeric(attr(which(table(pos)>1), "names"))

for(k in 1:length(uni)){

t.pos <- which(pos==uni[k])

pos <- pos[-t.pos[1]]

replace <- replace[-t.pos[1]]
}

if(length(unique(pos))==length(pos)) break
}
}
variables[i,pos]<- replace


}


dim(df.response)
dim(variables)
```

## Below code will give the final data with 100 rows and 100 columns.

```
final.data <- cbind(variables[1:100,],df.response[1:100,])
```

Welcome for other solutions. @LenGreski